# "SOUNDS LIKE" in diesel query

Tags: mysql, rust, rust-diesel

I want to query a field using MySQLs "SOUNDS LIKE".

SQL:

```sql
WHERE field SOUNDS LIKE "blah"
```

How to query this with diesel framework?

I thought of

```rust
.filter(sql("field SOUNDS LIKE ???"))
```

But how to inject (`bind()`) my value here with correct escaping?

Or is there a better way to filter using unsupported SQL?

**EDIT1:**

I found the infix_operator macro but it doesn't work. `SqlType`, `TypedExpressionType` and infix_operator macro is not found. But according to Github it's exactly there:

```rust
use diesel::sql_types::SqlType;
use diesel::expression::TypedExpressionType;
use diesel::expression::AsExpression;
use diesel::expression::Expression;

diesel::infix_operator!(SoundsLike, " SOUNDS LIKE ");

fn sounds_like<T, U, ST>(left: T, right: U) -> SoundsLike<T, U::Expression>
where
    T: Expression<SqlType = ST>,
    U: AsExpression<ST>,
    ST: SqlType + TypedExpressionType,
{
    SoundsLike::new(left, right.as_expression())
}
```

Comment: `.filter(sql("field SOUNDS LIKE 'blah'"))`?

Comment: The value comes from user input (=variable). Thought this is obvious :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found the infix_operator macro but it doesn't work. SqlType, TypedExpressionType and infix_operator macro is not found. But according to Github it's exactly there:

That's because you've looked at the master branch, which contains unreleased changes. One of them is the renaming of `diesel::infix_operator!` from [`diesel_infix_operator!`](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/macro.diesel_infix_operator.html)
By just using the variant from the latest release your code should just work:

```rust
#[macro_use] extern crate diesel;

use diesel::expression::AsExpression;
use diesel::expression::Expression;

diesel_infix_operator!(SoundsLike, " SOUNDS LIKE ");

fn sounds_like<T, U, ST>(left: T, right: U) -> SoundsLike<T, U::Expression>
where
    T: Expression<SqlType = ST>,
    U: AsExpression<ST>,
{
    SoundsLike::new(left, right.as_expression())
}
```

Comment: Still SqlType and TypedExpressionType can not be found. Using diesel 1.4.5. AsExpression and Expression are OK.

Comment: That's correct, I've missed that. The code is fixed now and should work fine with the 1.4.5 release.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind parameters with the [`bind`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/expression/struct.SqlLiteral.html) method:

```rust
table.filter(sql("SOUNDS LIKE ").bind::<Text, _>(input);
```

Comment: Not that elegant as I have to hard code the table and field name. But it works. Thanks